# What are the display parameters for a TFT LCD?

Tags: lcd, display, linux, system-on-chip

I want to use [this display](https://www.lcdtek.co.uk/img/cms/PDF/ETM070080BDH6-RoHS.pdf) with a system on module running Linux. I need to configure the device tree below with the parameters for the display so it will work properly. A description of these parameters can be found [here](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001945-13/reference/yocto/r_an_adding_custom_display.htmhttps://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001945-13/reference/yocto/r_an_adding_custom_display.htm).

```
/* ETM070080BDH6 display (7inch) */
            timing_wvga: 800x480 {
                clock-frequency = <33260000>;
                hactive = <800>;
                vactive = <480>;
                hback-porch = <88>;
                hfront-porch = <40>;
                vback-porch = <33>;
                vfront-porch = <10>;
                hsync-len = <128>;
                vsync-len = <2>;

                de-active = <1>;
                hsync-active = <0>;
                vsync-active = <0>;
                pixelclk-active = <1>;
            };
```

The problem is that I cannot identify the parameters correctly and some of them I think aren't mentioned in the datasheet. I searched for documentation regarding these parameters, but I found them with different notations and got confused.

**Does anybody know what are the parameters requested by the device tree? Also, what values should I put if they aren't given in the datasheet?**

Answer (score 1):

The values can be found in the Timing chapter 5 in the datasheet. If the datasheet does not say an exact value then a range of values between minimum and maximum values allowed.

Comment: Yes, I found the values in the datasheet, at chap. 5. My problem is that I don't know what is, e.g., the hback-porch value. Is it the HSYNC first horizontal data time? The notations are also different across documentations, so I cannot be sure. The only parameters I correctly identified in the datasheet are: clock-frequency, hactive, vactive, hsync-len and vsync-len.

Comment: Is the VESA DMT standard enough for a reference?

Comment: I looked at the VEST DMT standard, https://glenwing.github.io/docs/VESA-DMT-1.13.pdf, but I could not find helpful information.